# What's so secret about the OAuth secret?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm writing a web service which uses OAuth2 for authorization. I'm using C# and WCF, though this isn't really pertinent to my question. Having never used OAuth before, I've been doing my research. I'm on the "verify they're actually authorized to use this service" end of things. I think I have a pretty good idea of how OAuth2 works now, but one aspect of it still confounds me.

OAuth2 is token-based. The token is just text and contains some information, including a "secret" that only your application (the web service, in my case) and the Authorization Server knows. The secret can be just a text phrase or a huge string of semi-random characters (sort of like a GUID). This "proves" the user contacted the Authorization Server and got the secret from it. What confuses me is this only seems to prove that the user contacted the Authorization server sometime in the past. In fact, it doesn't even prove that. It just proves that the user knows the secret. The rest of the token (such as role, duration, other stuff) can all be faked. Once the user gets one token for the service he wants access to, they could whip up new tokens with falsified information as much as they like. In fact, there could be numerous servers set up with thousands of "secrets" for nefarious individuals to use at will. Of course, this wouldn't happen often, but it seems very possible.

Am I correct, or is there something I'm missing? Is this a known weakness of OAuth2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the Resource Server (or "service") receives a token, it needs to validate it. Depending on the token type it can check its signature that was created with the private key that Authorization Server has or it can call into the Authorization Server to validate the token. This way a user cannot forge a token: it would be impossible to forge the signature or to make the Authorization Server verify a token that it did not issue.

FWIW: you seem to be conflating the "token" and "client secret" and perhaps even the private key of the Authorization Server; they're all different concepts.

Comment: Thank you! None of the resources I've read talked about a signature (created with the private key) or about contacting the AS to verify. All I've seen was that the token contained a secret and other information. Contacting the AS itself or checking a signature makes a ton a sense, and it's a wonder I haven't come across it before. I guess I have to find better sources. Thanks again!